# SVCHOST uses a large amount of memory for short periods of time

Tags: windows-7, memory, svchost

Every now and again my laptop starts to be choppy (from lagging mouse response to complete freeze).
If I manage to open the Task Manager I find SVCHOST using up all the memory it can get. After a minute or two it releases the memory and the computer returns to normal.

What is the cause and how can I prevent this from happening?

I'm running Windows 7 with 8 Gb RAM.

Comment: does installing the update fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the cause and how can I prevent this from happening?

This is the Windows Update service which scans for new updates. Microsoft tries to fix it with several updates.

Install this update to fix it:

**Windows Update Client for Windows 7: March 2016**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138612

Before trying to install the MSU, stop the Windows Update service (`net stop wuauserv` from admin cmd.exe) to avoid a hang during setup.